# jQuery selectmenu and display content of selected menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I add contents to be called every time a different item is selected using jquery selectmenu? I've written the below code so far and want to add that call.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        fieldset {
          border: 0;
        }
        label {
          display: block;
          margin: 30px 0 0 0;
        }
        .overflow {
          height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#category" ).selectmenu();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo">
        <form action="#">
            <fieldset>
            <label for="preference">Pick a category</label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                  <option>Business</option>
                  <option>School</option>
                  <option Sport="selected">Medium</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <div>
            content of select category.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a dynamic content for each of the options provided. If someone picks Business, information about business should be displayed and also for the rest.

Comment: From where you'll fetch the contents corresponding to each category?

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution :

```js
$( function() {
  $('#Business').hide();
  $('#School').hide();
  $('#Medium').hide();
  $( "#category" ).selectmenu();
  $('#category').change(function(){
        var value=$(this).val(); 
   $('.information').empty().append(($('#'+value).html()));
  });
} );
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
select{
  width:300px;
}
.information{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.felixnagel.com/selectmenu/ui/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js"></script>

<div class="demo">
  <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="preference">Pick a category</label>
      <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option>Business</option>
        <option>School</option>
        <option>Medium</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div class="information">

  </div>
  <div id="Business">
    Content of bussinesss<br>
  </div>
  <div id="School">
    Content of school<br>
  </div>
  <div id="Medium">
    Content of medium<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXtpC/2517/)